# What am I doing wrong in this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

```
def pregunta 
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase
    if reply == 'si'
        puts 'Correcto'
    end

    if reply == 'no'
        puts 'Incorrecto'
    end
end

pregunta 'alfkjdasñlfj?'
```

After I ask a question ("pregunta" is question in english), the program should tell me if I'm right ("correcto") or wrong ("incorrecto") when I enter an answer ("si" or "no"). Instead of getting an answer, I get an "ArgumentError". What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p194

Comment: Please make the title relevant to the question .. (also, your method does not take any parameters; pay attention to *when* the error occurs)

Comment: (Hint: here is a minimum failing case: `def x; end; x "foo"`. Note *when* the errors occurs and read the full message.)

Answer (score 2):

pregunta doesn't take a parameter, but you pass one anyways. I might be wrong, but wasn't what you were trying to do something like this:

```
def pregunta(preg)
    puts preg
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase
    if reply == 'si'
        puts 'Correcto'
    end

    if reply == 'no'
        puts 'Incorrecto'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in a value to the function call, you're reading it from the terminal.  Call the function and *then* enter in your string.

```
pregunta
si
Correcto
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any parameters in your method declaration.

You'll need something like this:

```
def pregunta(foo)
   if foo == 'bar'
      true
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling pregunta 'alfkjdasñlfj?' but that method has no arguments.

```
def pregunta(answer) 
    reply = answer.chomp.downcase
    if reply == 'si'
        puts 'Correcto'
    end

    if reply == 'no'
        puts 'Incorrecto'
    end
end

pregunta gets
```

maybe ?